# Excel freezes when using VBA to open a workbook from network

Tags: vba, excel

I have an odd problem. The cabinetry business I work for uses an Excel workbook for pricing. We price the job in sections which are saved in multiple workbooks, and after we're done we have a macro which compiles the prices into one file. All our files are stored on a NAS which is accessed through the network.

Here's where it gets strange. Occasionally, when compiling the prices, the macro will freeze while opening the source workbook. No error, it just gets stuck loading. I can tell by walking through the code that it does open the workbook, but it instantly gets stuck. I've tried it with and without Application.EnableEvents enabled, and neither one works. It's being opened as read-only, with update links turned off.

On our pricing worksheet we have 2 buttons, one which names and saves the file, the other which does the same plus resetting the workbook for the next section of the job. The save portions of both macros are nearly identical, the main difference being the reset portion. The problem I described *only* happens when I first use the "Save & Reset" button, then reprice it and use the "Save/Save As" button. The first workbook works fine during compilation, the second freezes it. If I open the problem workbook and re-save it the problem goes away. I've been hammering my head against this one all morning and I have yet to figure out what's going on. Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

**Code**

Save/Save As macro

```
Dim FldrName, ThisFile As String

ThisFile = Sheet3.Range("FileName")
FldrName = Sheet3.Range("FolderName")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "\\qctnas\Google Drive\Production\" & FldrName & "\" & _
ThisFile & ".xlsm", 52

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Save and Reset macro

```
Dim FldrName, ThisFile As String
Dim Ans As Integer

'This section is identical to the previous macro

ThisFile = Sheet3.Range("FileName")
FldrName = Sheet3.Range("FolderName")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "\\qctnas\Google Drive\Production\" & FldrName & "\" & _
ThisFile & ".xlsm", 52

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True


Before  'A simple sub which turns off EnableEvents, ScreenUpdating, and DisplayAlerts

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "\\qctnas\Google Drive\Production\- IP Proposal\QCT Proposal" & _ 
".xlsm", 52  'Saves as a copy to keep the original from being changed

'This portion resets the values on the workbook

Ans = MsgBox("Reset Specs?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

If Ans = 6 Then
    With Sheet3
        .Range("ChangeToNA").Value = "Not applicable"
        .Range("ChangeToChooseFinish").Value = "CHOOSE FINISH"
        .Range("ChangeToYes").Value = "Yes"
        .Range("ChangeToNo").Value = "No"
        .Range("ChangeToStandard").Value = "Standard"
        .Range("JIEmptyThese").Value = ""
        .Range("CMAP").Value = 50
    End With
Else
    Sheet3.Range("JIEmptyWhenNotReset").Value = ""
End If

With Sheet11
    .Range("DCEmptyThese").Value = ""
    .Range("ChangeTo1").Value = "1"
    .Range("ChangeTo4").Value = "4"""
    .Range("MiscCrown").Value = "(Misc. Crown)"
    .Range("MiscMolding").Value = "(Misc. Molding)"
    .Range("ChangeToShipV").Value = "(Ship/V)"
    .Range("ChangeTo8Dollars").Value = 8
End With

With Sheet2
    .Range("IEmptyThese").Value = ""
    .Range("DeleteValidationInThese").Validation.Delete
End With

Sheet2.Unprotect
Application.Goto Sheet2.Range("a68"), True
Sheet2.Range("b82").Select

Application.Goto Sheet11.Range("a1"), True
Sheet11.Range("b4").Select

Sheet3.Unprotect
Application.Goto Sheet3.Range("DelDrop").Offset(-1, -2), True
Sheet3.Range("DelDrop").Select

After  'Mirrors the Before sub
```

Compilation Macro

```
Dim IWB As Workbook
Dim IWBJ, IWBI As Worksheet
Dim FldrName, JobFldr, FileName As String

Before

JobFldr = Sheet1.Range("FolderName")
FldrName = "\\qctnas\Google Drive\Production\" & JobFldr & "\"

FileName = Dir(FldrName & "*QCT Proposal*.xlsm")

Do While FileName <> ""
    Set IWB = Workbooks.Open(FldrName & FileName, False, True)
    Set IWBI = IWB.Sheets("Invoice")
    Set IWBJ = IWB.Sheets("Job Info")

    'Copy info

    FileName = Dir()
Loop

After
```

Comment: Could you please attach the relevant codes from the macros and/or buttons?

Comment: A network failure could cause Excel to hang or fail to load.

Comment: @Mistella Not a problem! I've added it to the post. 

HackSlash, that's possible. We are accessing it through a network. But it consistently works as soon as we open the problem workbook and save it again. Any idea what would cause a network error?

Comment: Have you tried to cause the freezing issue (via the saving order you mention) while stepping through the code? If so, do you have any idea which line(s) may be problematic? Or does the freezing only happen while the macro is running freely?

Comment: Your code seems to be missing bits. Where is `Err:` ?

Comment: @Mistella I have. When I trigger the line that opens the workbook it does open (the name shows up on the title bar), but that's when it gets stuck. AJD, I removed some of the code to declutter it, but I missed that piece. `Err:` displays a msgbox, then turns EnableEvents and ScreenUpdating back on.

Comment: And the value of the variable `FileName` is the actual name of an existing file when that happens? Another thing to check: when I'm stepping past a `Workbook.Open`, for some reason the macro sometimes starts running freely instead of stopping on the next line. Have you tried putting a breakpoint at `Set IWBI = IWB.Sheets("Invoice")` before stepping into the `Workbook.Open` line? This could help verify that it's the `Workbook.Open` line that's causing an issue, and not some code later in the sub.

Comment: Yes, `FileName` matches the actual name of the file. And when I step through it stops exactly at the `Workbook.Open` line. I put a break there, and as soon as I execute that line it acts like it's opening the file, and it displays the name up top, but it just hangs. 2 other notes: (1) This macro worked fine for several months, but started causing issues after a recent system overhaul. (2) It works most of the time. The _only_ time it hangs is when I save it in the sequence mentioned earlier.

Comment: @qctjulian When opening the workbooks: Is it the same workbook that the code always freezes on opening, or does it freeze regardless of which workbook it's trying to open? Do any of the workbooks you're opening have any macros of their own, triggered by being opened?

Comment: @Mistella Yes. It will consistently lock up on the same file. Opening it and re-saving that file using the _same macro_ fixes the problem, but that's a pain when you're dealing with 6-8 files per job. Oh, and it has to be closed, then opened and re-saved to fix it. Just running the macro again won't fix it. The problem is duplicable; we run 2 machines and it happens on both.

The workbooks that are being opened do have macros that run when opened, but I've tried running it with `Application.EnableEvents` both `True` and `False` and neither helps.

Comment: @qctjulian I know, with userforms, that sometimes when the vba is busy for a long time, that can cause excel to stop responding. A fix to that is to add a `DoEvents` line before the `Next item` line in `For` loops; or before the `Wend` line in `While` loops. **Maybe** if you put `DoEvents` right after the `Workbook.Open` line, and inside other code loops in the other macros (particularly in the trouble workbook), it would help prevent Excel from freezing.

Comment: @Mistella Another good point. I ran across the `DoEvents` option yesterday, but no luck there either. The length of the macro doesn't seem to affect when it locks up. I can have anywhere from 2 to 6 workbooks, and the same one will lock it up regardless where it is in sequence. It seems to be something with how the workbook is saved, but I have yet to find any consistent cause.

Comment: @qctjulian Could it be a file size issue? Is the trouble workbook significantly larger than the other workbooks?

Comment: Not significantly. I tested it on 2 workbooks, and the first one (which worked fine with the compile macro) was 210kb. The second one (which didn't work) was 211kb. When I opened the second one and re-saved it the file size dropped to 204kb. Then the macro worked, no problem. Do you think something is going on there?

Comment: Since the issue is just related to the one specific workbook, I'm starting to suspect that there might be an issue with one of the macro's within that workbook. _(I am assuming that when that workbook is opened via the code, that it's macro(s) are kicked-off.)_ Would you be able to post any of that code?

Comment: Sorry, I hope I didn't confuse the issue with that last comment. The 2 workbooks I tested were from the same template. The only difference between them is a few small bits of info. I'd be glad to post more code for the workbook, but it has quite a bit in it. Is there something specific you're looking for?

Comment: I just tried stepping through the `Workbooks.Open` portion with the workbook that works, and nothing is triggered (at least nothing that shows up in the VBA window) when I open the workbook. It goes from the `Workbooks.Open` line straight to the `Set IWBI` line. For what that's worth...

Comment: Where does the compile macro fit into the code flow?. The other two you posted, you mentioned are activated by a button. Are they activated any other way? What activates the compile macro? Is it in the same workbooks, or a different one?

Comment: The compile macro resides in a third workbook, which contains basic information about the job and customer and is used to create prefilled workbooks from templates. The compile macro is triggered by a button within that workbook. None of the three are activated any way other than a button press.

Comment: You said the issue only happens when you do the save/reset and then the save/save as macros. You also said it only happens with one specific workbook. Is that specific workbook the only one in which you've used the saving macros in that order? Or have you tested the macro order with a different workbook? Also, does the trouble workbook always have issues, or only after using the saving macros in the issue-triggering order?

Comment: As in, we have one template. We fill it out, and hit "Save & Reset". We fill another, and hit "Save." Now we have 2 workbooks from the same template. The first one works fine with the compile macro, but the second one causes the issue. Any other that we create after the second one will have the same issue until we open it and re-save (using the same macro that we used to save it in the first place). It's maddening... If we create 6, #2-6 will all freeze the compile macro. #1 works, #2 freezes. Re-save #2, and #3 will freeze it.

Comment: Also, this is the only workbook we use that both saves and resets in the same macro, but we use the same basic macro in several other workbooks. Thanks for your help in trying to resolve this thing!

Comment: Clarification question: #1 (_works fine_) is from `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "\\qctnas\Google Drive\Production\" & FldrName & "\" & 
ThisFile & ".xlsm", 52` and #2 (_problematic_) is from `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "\\qctnas\Google Drive\Production\- IP Proposal\QCT Proposal " & _ 
".xlsm", 52`?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "\\qctnas\Google Drive\Production\- IP Proposal\QCT Proposal " & _ ".xlsm", 52` saves it as an intermediary file. It saves as that one to protect #1 after it's completed. We don't want to clear the values on the original lest it gets saved after it's cleared and that one gets overwritten. So that one happens between #1 and #2. Each workbook being referenced in the compile macro (where the issue happens) has been saved using the `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "\\qctnas\Google Drive\Production\" & FldrName & "\" & ThisFile & ".xlsm", 52` line.

Comment: Is this a typo from you posting the code or is this line actually missing the underline space at the line break: `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "\\qctnas\Google Drive\Production\" & FldrName & "\" & 
ThisFile & ".xlsm", 52`  
vs: `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "\\qctnas\Google Drive\Production\" & FldrName & "\" & _
ThisFile & ".xlsm", 52`

Comment: Wasn't sure that was clear. Just in case you're unaware, when vba code wraps around to the line below, it needs to be indicated by including: " _" at the end of every line except the last physical line of the code line/block (without the quotation marks) Similar to what was done with the intermediate saving.

Comment: Ah, yes. That's a typo here. In the workbook it's all on one line.

Comment: Have you tried commenting-out the `On Error Resume Next` lines, then running through the macro order? If it is an issue with the saving, it's possible that the `Resume Next` line is masking any other error messages that may be helpful.

Comment: I have, yes. The `On Error Resume Next` line just jumps it down if the workbook already exists. The `SaveAs` line throws an error if a file with that name already exists in that location, so the next line saves it instead. I thought the fact that it saves it the second time might be the reason why it works after re-opening it and saving it, but that cycle only works if the workbook is closed as well. Just re-saving it won't fix it.

Comment: That's interesting. I have **Excel 2016**, and the `.SaveAs` does not throw an error. It opens a message box warning about the file already existing _unless_ the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`. If the warning is suppressed, then the `SaveAs` simply overwrites the existing file. I have been unable to get to a situation (with or without the `On Error Resume Next`) where this `If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False` is true and leads to the `ThisWokbook.Save` line. What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Excel 365. I tried it without the `Resume Next` line and it saved fine like you said. It's been a while since I wrote that part, so it may have been an oversight at that point. I've learned most of what I know within the last year, and I must have written that code before I started using `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`. I updated the code in my workbook. Cleaner is always better! I'll report back on whether or not that helps our problem.

Comment: Just following up on this one. Changing the `Save As` section seemed to fix the problem. It now simply turns off `Application.DisplayAlerts` before saving. I'm not sure why that would have caused the problem, but apparently it did. But it's working smoothly now, and has been for about a month. Thanks for your help @Mistella!

Comment: @qctjulian I'm glad I could help. I would also like to explain that since we hope such questions will be useful for future coders, generally instead of editing the question to contain the corrected code; it is encouraged to post an answer (an accept it?). This also indicates to the rest of the community that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning the below code fixed the issue. Not sure why.

*Changed this:*

```
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "\\qctnas\Google Drive\Production\" & FldrName & "\" & _
ThisFile & ".xlsm", 52
If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then ThisWorkbook.Save
On Error GoTo 0
```

*to this:*

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "\\qctnas\Google Drive\Production\" & FldrName & "\" & _
ThisFile & ".xlsm", 52
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the reputation to roll the question back (to before-corrected problematic code), so that this answer makes sense.